# i am try to include theme in my high chart but on web page no theme is apply, only chart is visible

Tags: javascript, html, themes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Start With Highchart</title>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code i am simply trying to start with highchart. this code display highchart but no theme is applying to it. how to work  with this line. it is not included. In console "GET http://localhost/js/themes/gray.js " this error is shown.

Comment: the error is 404.

Comment: check your js file path which you include in your js path directory and provide the right path for access your require js in html page.

Comment: it is done, but yet theme is not apply.

Comment: what the error is showing now...

Comment: no error is showing.

Comment: have you checked on view source that your gray.js file is found or not.

Comment: i already check and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this one..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Start With Highchart</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'bar'
},
title: {
    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit eaten'
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [1, 0, 4]
}, {
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 7, 3]
}]
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This complete code works perfectly.  I userd the cloudfare CDN for the theme file, which can be replaced by path to local file if you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Start With Highchart</title>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.14/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: path is okay and and i put file on right path, now it is not giving any error but  theme is still not display.

Comment: I edited the answer based on your comment. check it out.

Comment: where to put this Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);

Comment: @AmitJoshi this will give you an error. **<script type="text/javascript" src=".js/themes/gray.js"></script>**

Comment: use whatever path works for you. I havent seen your folder structure so the path i wrote was an assumption that there is a folder called `js` on the same directory as this script file. if `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/themes/gray.js"></script>` was working, then use the same path.

Comment: I updated the code with complete solution. It works as is. Check and let me know.